# Comportamiento de clases bootstrap: pull-right / pull-left

Tags: html, bootstrap-3

Estoy maquetando unos botones con *bootstrap 3*, alineados a la derecha, siempre me ha llamado la atención que para que aparezcan así:

```
                                              -------------   -------------
                                              |  botón 1  |   |  botón 2  |
                                              -------------   -------------
```

Hay que poner primero el código del "botón 2" y luego del "botón 1", de la siguiente forma:

```
<div class="row">
    <a class="btn btn-primary pull-right">botón 2</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary pull-right" style="margin-right: 1rem">botón 1</a>
</div>
```

Es decir que al usar `pull-right` se invierte su "orden natural", **¿por qué ocurre esto?**

Código de prueba:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Pruebas alineación con Bootstrap 3</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <style type="text/css">
        .content,
        .row {
            border : 1px solid grey;
            margin : 5%;
            padding: 5%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content">
        <h1>Pruebas alineación con Bootstrap 3</h1>

        <div class="row">
            <p>Botones alineados a la derecha</p>
            <a class="btn btn-primary pull-right">botón 2</a>
            <a class="btn btn-primary pull-right" style="margin-right: 1rem">botón 1</a>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <p>Botones alineados a la Izquierda</p>
            <a class="btn btn-primary pull-left" style="margin-right: 1rem">botón 1</a>
            <a class="btn btn-primary pull-left">botón 2</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Es por que en dicha clase, se está aplicando la propiedad `float: right`. Esta propiedad hace que el elemento sea "empujado" en dirección hasta el elemento flotante más cercano, rompiendo su flujo normal. Puede consultar información [aquí.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float#How_floated_elements_are_positioned)

Comment: @Jheyman Mejia Entonces, el comportamiento de la *clase bootstrap* `pull-right`, es en realidad el propio y se debe únicamente a la propiedad `float:right`. Para probar esto basta con sustituir la clase `pull-right` por otra personalizada que solo aplique esta propiedad al elemento y se observará que se produce exactamente el mismo resultado.

Comment: Es correcto Orici, me atrevería a decir que tiene un comportamiento similar a `direction: rtl`, sólo que aplicado a elementos completos y no a textos.